# Typescript wrap third party libraries handle types

Tags: typescript

I want to create an abstraction for third party libraries. For example:

```
import { format as _format }  from 'date-fns';

export function format(date, format, options) {
  return _format(date, format, options)
}
```

The problem is that I need to copy and maintain the original types, including the overloading. Is there any other smart way to do it?

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you want to type your `format` abstraction, but don't want to type it by yourself and use the types of the `date-fns` package?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: You could `export const format: typeof _format = (...args) => _format(..args);` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUYBciwgLYBGApgE4CU2AzlCTGAOYDcAUKJLAsqhtroaQBpElKjTr0KwsQxZto8JCnRYc+YiSGUA-KNoNJ1PfUQBvZokQkiUECSQBye8wC+zN1ACeAByKIAYqiIALyInj5wwFxwLMwQCNSIBACGJNgBcMGIaGTBAHyIjoxAA

Comment: If you're not changing or adding something to implementation you could just re-export the required methods: `export { format } from 'date-fns';`

Comment: Thanks, @AlekseyL, both your solutions work.